# How do I create a List of Lists of a given type where the size could vary based on inputs?

Tags: scala, list, range

I need to create a function that returns a List[List[Option[Double]]], where the function takes a List[String] of stock market symbols, and a Range of the years the function must look at, so something like Range[2000, 2019, 1].

The function will call another function:

```
def price(symbol: String, year: Int) : Option[Double] = ...
```

This returns an Option[Double] either Some(double) or None. So lets say the function I am trying to create takes List("GOOG", "AAPL") and Range[2010, 2013, 1], the results should look something like:

```
List(List(Option for Google 2010, Option for Apple 2010),   
     List(Option for Google 2011, Option for Apple 2011),   
     List(Option for Google 2012, Option for Apple 2012)).
```

I am not allowed to use 'var' in my code, only 'val' and of course this means once declared there can be no modifications.

So what I am asking is how do I create this List[List[Option[Double]]] when I don't know how many values will be in the List[String] or the Range. I am assuming it is not possible to dot this in a for loop and it must all happen during the declaration of the list.

So far, the only thing that I can think of would be to do something along the lines of:

```
val returnList : List[List[Option[Double]]] = List(x => rangeIn.foreach(List(y => symbolsIn.foreach(price(y, x)))))
```

Answer (score 1):

You might use `map` instead of `foreach` which has a return type of `Unit`.

For example:

```
val returnList : List[List[Option[Double]]] =
  rangeIn.map(r => symbolsIn.map(s => price(s, r)))
```

[Scala demo](https://ideone.com/UdCbnG)

Comment: In addition the second map could be a flatMap to get rid of Option all together and remove possible Nones.

Comment: @Saskia Thank you for your comment, that is correct. The code would then look like `val returnList : List[List[Double]] = rangeIn.map(r => symbolsIn.flatMap(s => price(s, r)))`

Answer (score 1):

@the-fourth-bird 's answer is the way to go.

But you asked if it's possible in a for loop. In scala you rarely see traditional for loops and you usually use a for-comprehension. It doesn't look as nice as the other answer, but it is possible.

It desugars to almost the same code, except for a bit of wrapping.

```
val prices = (for {
    s <- List(symbols)
    r <- range
} yield s.flatMap(price(_, r)))
```